# How to get the latest revision id for a specific path excluding merges in a given branch using JGit?

Tags: java, git, version-control, jgit

I'm working on converting a complicated Mercurial query to Git. I found that JGit can be used to achieve the same without handcrafting the query in the code. The goal is to get the latest revision id based on a path filter if the file was modified in the branch and exclude merges. This is what I have so far :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
try (Repository repository = CookbookHelper.openJGitCookbookRepository()) {
    Ref head = repository.getRef("HEAD");
    //Use pathFilter to filter this just for maps directory
    PathFilter pathFilter = PathFilter.create("directory/path/*")

    RevWalk walk = new RevWalk(repository)

    walk.setRevFilter(RevFilter.NO_MERGES)
    walk.setTreeFilter(AndTreeFilter.create(PathFilterGroup.create(pathFilter))

    RevCommit commit = walk.parseCommit(${REVISION});
    RevTree tree = commit.getTree();
    // now use a TreeWalk to iterate over all files in the Tree recursively and you can set Filters to narrow down the results if needed
    try (TreeWalk treeWalk = new TreeWalk(repository)) {
         treeWalk.addTree(tree);
         while (treeWalk.next()) {
           // Some custom logic here
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

I'm kind of blocked after getting the `TreeWalk`. Any help is appreciated!

Edit:
This is the Mercurial query I'm working on converting:

```
hg log -r max((merge() and branch(${REVISION}) and ancestors(${REVISION}) " \
            "and descendants(not branch(${REVISION}) and file('directory/path/*') " \
            "and not ancestors(min(branch(${REVISION}))))) or max( file('directory/path/*') " \
            "and branch(${REVISION}) and ancestors(${REVISION})) " \
            "or min(branch(${REVISION})) and public() or p1(min(branch(${REVISION})))) --template {node}
```

Comment: With plain Git that would be `git log --no-merges <branch> -- path/to/a/file` (that doesn't engage rename detection though).

Comment: I don't know anything about using JGit, but I will note that the Mercurial query definitely cannot be transliterated directly to Git, as the "branch(...)" concept doesn't translate properly: in Mercurial, once a commit is on some branch, that's the *only* branch it's *ever* on, while in Git, the set of branches (plural) that contain any given commit changes dynamically. The min(), max(), and phase tests like public() are also untranslatable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yor `RevWalk` setup is quite close I think. What is missing is to set the sort order to show newer commits first and set the 'point' from where to start the walk. In your case, the starting point would be the branch in question.

```java
RevWalk walk = new RevWalk( repository )
walk.setRevFilter( RevFilter.NO_MERGES )
walk.setTreeFilter( AndTreeFilter.create( PathFilterGroup.create( pathFilter ) );

walk.sort( RevSort.COMMIT_TIME_DESC, true );
walk.markStart( walk.parseCommit( repository.resolve( "refs/heads/branch-name" ) );
if( walk.next() != null ) {
  // now the RevWalk points to the newest commit in which the 
  // file was modified in the branch, excluding merges.
}

walk.close();
```